Next JS with Pusher presence channels, can't listen to events even after channel authorized
My issue is that I successfully authorized my channel and I'm getting a POST /api/pusher/auth 200 response code as expected from the docs but the basic events such as "pusher:subscription_succeeded" and "pusher:member_added" aren't being hit.
Here is the pusher server and client
import Pusher from "pusher";
import pusherJs from "pusher-js";

export const pusherServer = new Pusher({
  appId: process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID!,
  key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_APP_KEY!,
  secret: process.env.PUSHER_APP_SECRET!,
  cluster: "us2",
  useTLS: true,
});

export const pusherClient = new pusherJs(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PUSHER_APP_KEY!, {
  cluster: 'us2',  authEndpoint: "api/pusher/auth",
});

Here is the client side
useEffect(() =\> {
  if (session?.user) {
      const user = validateUsersSchema(session?.user);
      setUser(user);
    
      const presenceChannel = pusherClient.subscribe("presence-channel")
    
      presenceChannel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", () => {
        console.log("New User in presence channel")
      })
    
      presenceChannel.bind("pusher:member_added", (member: PresenceChannelData) => {
        console.log(member);
      })
    
      presenceChannel.bind("pusher:member_removed", (member: PresenceChannelData) => {
        console.log(member);
      })

Here is the api/pusher/auth route
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const body = await req.text();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(body);
  const socket_id = params.get("socket_id")!;
  const channel_name = params.get("channel_name")!;
  console.log(socket_id, channel_name);
  try {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    if (session) {
      if (session.user) {
        // Authenticated by knowing user is in our DB
        const user = validateUsersSchema(session.user);
        console.log(user);
        const auth = pusherServer.authorizeChannel(socket_id, channel_name, {
          user_id: user.id,
          user_info: {
            username: user.name,
            activityStatus: user.activityStatus,
            online: user.online
          }
        })
        console.log(auth);
        return NextResponse.json({ auth });
      }
    } else {
      return NextResponse.json({success: false}, { status: 404 });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return NextResponse.json({ err }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

I'm also getting the proper authorization string when I console.log(auth)

{
channel_data: '{"user_id":"66b1771683f79688fd09e509","user_info":{"username":"RafaelB","activityStatus":"ONLINE","online":true}}',
auth: 'e63f526933f87ce4309e:68acd9c7cb6dda20b6108c91285bdcd13c4f10cf5d8d5cdf32364888a9e6608f'

Assumed it was all channles not working but my public channnels work as expected

